# Does a sailor who is abroad for 6 months shorten prayer for the whole period?

Tags: salat-al-qasr

I am a Sailor. Every time we join ship we stay on board for 6 months. During that time we normally don't stay at any particular place for few days (2-3). Should we Qasar (Shorten prayer) during the 6 months period?

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in our [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: This is a good question, as basically one would say according to what you've said qasr (shirtening prayers) would be the usual case, but as it is your job to travel, maybe scholars have different views. Except for ibadis whom consider qasr as allowed if you left what you call home. I've read something similar from ibn Taymiyyah too.